# Make jQuery function run only inside a specific div id or class

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function to change the **href** on a webpage.  How do I make this script only run inside the `#container` div?

```
$('a[href*="example.com"]').each(function(){
 var index = this.href.indexOf(".com/");
 this.href = this.href.slice(0, index+5)
})
```

I've tried this,

```
$('#container').$('a[href*="example.com"]').each(function(){
 var index = this.href.indexOf(".com/");
 this.href = this.href.slice(0, index+5)
})
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: You can only use one $(..) per statement. Once you've got a jquery object, you keep chaining statements: $('#container').someFunction().someOtherFunction()....

Comment: before it, i've tried the $() per statement. like this $('#container').('a[href*="example.com"]'), but it same, won't work.

Comment: @frenchie whether if so it could using **('# container', 'a [href * =' example.com')** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('#container').find('a[href*="example.com"]').each(function(){
    var index = this.href.indexOf(".com/");
    this.href = this.href.slice(0, index+5)
})
```

Or use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('#container a[href*="example.com"]').each(function(){
    var index = this.href.indexOf(".com/");
    this.href = this.href.slice(0, index+5)
})
```

You can also try a slightly different version

```
$('#container').find('a[href*="example.com"]').attr('href', function(idx, href){
    var index = href.indexOf(".com/");
    return href.slice(0, index + 5)
})
```

Comment: You don't need to use find, you can just merge the selectors with a space.

Comment: oh my gosh, I forget the "find" section.. thank you. i know this question is easy, I will learn more about jquery. thanks..

Comment: @John what are you mean about merge the selectors with a space? how

Comment: @ArunPJohny okay, with descendant selector, that further reduce source capacity. which is more ideal?

Comment: One call to jQuery is better than two.

Comment: @Barmar but a jsprf profiling says a slightly different story http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector/36

Comment: @HerryKusmadi Based on the performance profiles I've seen I would recommend using `.find()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny i'm using jquery 1.10.1. you change each(function){} TO .attr('href', function(idx, href){}. they have the same result. what the difference?

Comment: The second method which uses attr instead of .each provides a callback that gets called once per matched element. The callback provides the index of the current element in the matched set as well as the element itself. Check out the jQuery documentation for that here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr